# Table from sqoop 1.4.7 importing into HDFS is fine. while importing into hive 3.1.1

Tags: hadoop, import, hive, sqoop

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sqoopdb --username dsa -P 
             --split-by id --columns id,name --table employee --target-dir /test1 
             --fields-terminated-by "," --hive-import --create-hive-table 
             --hive-table employee_sqoop
```

Table from sqoop 1.4.7 importing into HDFS is fine. while  importing into hive 3.1.1 getting

> ERROR [main] tool.ImportTool: Import failed: java.io.IOException: Hive CliDriver exited with status=1

This is pseudo hadoop 3.1.1 cluster with hbase , sqoop , hive with latest versions....

1. I copy the libthrift*.jar file from hive/lib into sqoop/lib directory
2. And also  I set HBASE_HOME to a non-existing path
3. copy jackson-annotations-2.9.5.jar,jackson-core-2.9.5.jar,jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar files into sqoop/lib folder*

```
ERROR [main] tool.ImportTool: Import failed: java.io.IOException: Hive CliDriver exited with status=1   at
 org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.executeScript(HiveImport.java:355)
    at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.importTable(HiveImport.java:241)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:537)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:628)    at
 org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)     at
 org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)  at
 org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)    at
 org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)     at
 org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:243)     at
 org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252)
```

Comment: This is detailed log file https://pastebin.com/t57AA4Yz

Comment: **issue solved i followed by these steps**                                                                    1.I copy the libthrift*.jar file from hive/lib into sqoop/lib directory                       
2.And also I set HBASE_HOME to a non-existing path                                  
3.copy jackson-annotations-2.9.5.jar,jackson-core-2.9.5.jar,jackson-databind 2.9.5.jar files from /usr/local/hive/lib into sqoop/lib folder                                                                  
4.move the lowest version(2.3.1) jackson*.jar files sqoop/lib to backup loacation (/usr/local/backup)

Comment: If you solved your own issue you can write an answer and accept it